# Moveable Do Piano for Ear Training Verification

Tags: ear-training, solfege

I have been working on moveable-do ear training for a while now.  I would like either a keyboard app where you can change the pitch of the C note or an app that will let you play some kind of solfege representation and choose the pitch of the Do.

The idea is that I hear a melody and I think I correctly hear it in terms of notes of the scale, but I want to check myself.  But I don't want to have to deal with verifying it by picking it out on a piano keyboard and also transposing in my head between different key signatures.  Ear training is hard enough without dealing with that.

I have periodically searched for something like this on the Android app store or web and cannot find anything.

Comment: If you can't find an app, you can get an actual instrument.  I have a 30-year-old synthesizer that transposes; I suppose any decent electronic keyboard would.  However, I doubt you'll be able to get the Smithsonian to let you use [Irving Berlin's piano](https://music.si.edu/object-day/irving-berlins-transposing-upright-piano).

Comment: Vtc as this site isn't about recommending equipment of any kind. Ear training is o.k. to a point. Referring to an actual instrument makes a lot more sense of it all. Phoog's idea is good.